# Explanation needed for this differential equation problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was looking at the problem and failed to tackle:

[image]

### MY ATTEMPT:

From the given D.E. we get,  $x_1''-x_1=1$ so that general solution is given by: $\,\,x_1(t)=c_1e^t+c_2e^{-t}-1$.Similarly,$\,\,\,y_1(t)=c_3e^t+c_4e^{-t}-1$.From the given options ,I guess 3 or 4 be the right choice but I just could not get the right result.Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try to write $\frac{d}{dt}X $ explicitly for all possible choices and look what it gives. No need to use second derivatives.